Unwanted border/edge after pathfinder
I need to merge two shapes using pathfinder. I dnt understand why am getting the edge after applying pathfinder. it should be one whole shape, am not supposed to see the border of those two. it seems like I have grouped them.. please help.. I dnt want these extra points.I need to get rid of these. Thank you.


Hi. Which pathfinder operation did you use?  Merge? Did you just press the button? Did you hold down Alt/Option?  There are too many unknowns here. Please share more information on how you got to this stage.

Hi, Billy, Actually its messy, I took a stroke with zero pt. then sliced the circle into two using divide and also there was a shape laye (A human hand, I was rigging a character for animation) I took all the shapes placed a stroke (0 pt) above them all and select them all applied 'divide' from path finder. then I took half of the circle and half of the hand and applied 'unite' from pathfinder, thts how I ended up with that weird result. I thought  'unite' will make them two into one. but I was worng.

I cant attach any gif here. no matter how tiny they are. so I cud not attach the whole thing. I tried.

The boolean operations don't really work properly with a stroke and a filled object. It would be better simply to expand the appearance of the stroked path, turning it into a filled object, then the boolean operations will work as expected, The reason for this is that a stroke is just an attribute added to a path, it's not a closed path containing a fill (such as a circle or a rectangle).

BTW you can attach GIFs here, but it has to be fairly a fairly short screen capture. There's an upper file size limit - I can't remember exactly, but I think it has to be less than 2mb. So if the GIF upload fails, then the file size is the issue.

Thank you so much. You all act as my teacher. I learn alwys from you all. I am really greateful.

yeah my gif are alwys above 50 mb! I wonder why! My gif acts as if I screen record them in james webber telescope resolution! rolling eyes!

Full screen gifs will be large. So try and confine the physical size of it. Maybe just a few hundred by a few hundred pixels.  There are some screen recorders out there which allow you to select a smaller area. I use ShareX, but it's for Windows only. You can also configure it to lower the frame rate. Less frames = less data = smaller file sizes.

Thnak you so much. I will use that from now on. I have windows too. am old school.

It seems you didn't apply the pathfinder in merge mode. Perhaps you applied it while leaving another mode like divide. Another less likely explanation (but it's hard to be sure from your screenshot) is that the initial shapes were not overlapping.
Try one of the following steps:

repeat the operation after checking that you have only selected the desired shapes, and that in the pathfinder pannel, the merge mode is on;
use the shape builder tool (Shift + M on Windows), which is by default in merge mode and is handy to use with shapes as the one in your screenshot.

And a quick tip: just in case you might wanna use Ctrl + Y to go in the outline mode and check that your merge operation does not leave any edge.

Thank you so much.  I cant thank you eneough. I understand now where I was wrong.
